# Using Snakefile variables in config file [snakemake]

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

Is it possible to use variable from Snakefile in config file? In below example, I would like Snakefile to recognize 'foo' as variable name and use its value.

Snakefile:

```
from pathlib import Path

foo = Path('path_to_dir')

rule all:
   input:
       config['OUT_FILE')
```

Config file:

```
OUT_FILE: foo / "data/results/abc.png"
```

If this is not possible, is there an alternate solution that could be used?

Comment: Why do you want to save the path to a JPEG in your config file?
 I cannot see why this would be needed. Snakemake doesn't support dynamically modifying your configfile. If it's a path or a location, you shouldn't need to store it, it should be propagated via wildcards and rules (the basis of Snakemake). If it's a file, you shouldn't need to store it either because it should be tracked by the rule itself. You can pass variables between rules, but that can be problematic due to coupling issues. Please elaborate?

Comment: @TBoyarski My use case has rule-all's input files vary depending on the hardware used. My thinking was to control them via multiple config files with specific input files required. I could have hardcoded filepath, but thought using it via variable would provide better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a placeholder or relative path in the config and replace that programmatically once the config file has been parsed, at the beginning of the Snakefile. Remember, snakemake is python plus rule syntax, so you can use any python code directly in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks! Snakemake is awesome, btw!